# cURL follow redirect causing 500 server error

Tags: php, redirect, curl, cron

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of a PHP 'header' redirect using cURL so that it works within a cronjob triggered script.

The following code runs within a while loop (which I know works) but it returns a 500 internal server error when I try to run it, as though the request is timing out on the server (it should not take any more than 30 seconds).

Is there something wrong with the way I'm doing this:

```
<?php    

$url = 'http://exampleurl/?ld_LeadProductType=PROF&ld_contactFirstName='.rawurlencode($quotes['name']).'&ld_businessName='.rawurlencode($quotes['company_name']).'&QuotePrice=%20/%20Quote%20Price:'.number_format($quotes['quote'],2).'.';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 128);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    $redirectURL = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL );
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: A 500 internal server error means that the problem is most likely on the server's end. Start by checking your error logs on the server, and verify the data you're sending. You may want to take a look at [`http_build_query`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) instead of manually building the query string.